# How to track scores of list items if each item is unknown (it is users input)

Tags: python

I try to create a simple program for tracking students scores. This is my code, but I have no idea how to track students scores. Almost of the students are unknown and will always be different.

I am trying to detect wether the students' score is equal to 10.

```
name_list = []
enter_name = True

while enter_name:
    name = input("Name: ")
    name_list.append(name)
    if name == "end":
        enter_name = False
name_list = name_list[:-1]

#score = 0
#for word in name_list:
   #score = int(input(f"{word} = {score}"))
#I am not sure about the last part, i think i turned to wrong direction
```

Comment: Where in your code are you trying to check the students' scores?

Answer (score 1):

You should be using a dictionary keyed on student name. Values should be the student's score as an integer (because you want to compare against a constant value of 10).

As you're going to want integer input from the user, you'll need to validate it in order to avoid unwanted exceptions.

Consider this:

```
DB = {}

while (name := input('Enter student name: ')) != 'end':
    while True:
        try:
            DB[name] = int(input(f'Enter score for {name}: '))
            break
        except ValueError:
            print('Score should be an integer')

for k, v in DB.items():
    print(f'{k} {"Genius" if v >= 10 else v}')
```

**Sample:**

```
Enter student name: Fred
Enter score for Fred: abc
Score should be an integer
Enter score for Fred: 10
Enter student name: Mick
Enter score for Mick: 5
Enter student name: end
Fred Genius
Mick 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a python dictionary:

```
students_scores = {}

while True:
    name = input("Name: ")
    if name == "end":
        break
    score = int(input("Score: "))
    students_scores[name] = score
```

If you want to know whether a student has a score of 10, you can use `if students_scores[student] == 10:`.

Comment: Thanks, it is kind of that, maybe that what i really want to get impossible without using some modules. I want to have list of names and in dynamics add some points to any name in the list.

Comment: @nonlinear You cannot compare integers with strings

Comment: @fred right! My bad. I will edit the post.

Comment: @vic dictionaries exist exactly for this reason: you can do `students_scores[name] = new_score` to change the scores. I would advise you to learn more about dictionaries.